# 2 ram bars of same model work individually but not together after sleep

Tags: windows-10, memory, sleep

As title says, each of my 2 ram bars work individually without problems.
When both are installed the pc boots fine but when I click on sleep and try to turn PC on again I get a black screen and have to force shutdown.

I have tried every slot in every order. I set auto frequency in BIOS and it sets it to 2133 MHz (my mobo's max).
I would rather avoid Hybrid Sleep / Hibernate because I'm a frequent user (on an SSD). I have also tried BIOS reset.

My specs are

Motherboard:
MSI B150M Bazooka

RAM:
2 x Hynix hma81gu7afr8n-uh 8GB DDR4 2400T

CPU:
Intel i5 6600

OS:
Windows 10

The 2 ram bars seem identical:

[BIOS info first bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VriNl.jpg)

[BIOS info second bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ro9zc.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Updating the BIOS firmware fixed it!